# HTML - How to put text over a white background over a background image

Tags: html, css, text, background-image

I'm trying to emulate the following screenshot using HTML/CSS:

[image: screenshot]

I have the following component files to work with:

1) the header image
[image: header]

2) the background image
[image: background]

and

3) the text starting from "They All Laughed..." all the way to "new training method that I've discovered"

I've been able to make the background image into the background image in the html file. Any ideas as to how to make the header image centered and scaled to rest at the top of the page and then to have a white background immediately below the header so that I can place the text on top of it? (extra credit for the shadowing on the sides, although not necessary)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bayenelu/1/

Comment: thank you that is great. Any ideas on how to create the white background underneath the header? Also feel free to make it an answer and I will check/upvote your answer THANKS!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**HTML**

```
    <body background="http://i1155.photobucket.com/albums/p560/sean1rose/backgroundimage_zpsa6c55a2e.png">
<div id="mainContainer" align="center">
   <header>
    <img src="http://i1155.photobucket.com/albums/p560/sean1rose/headerimage_zps9efccb9d.png" width="700" >
   </header>
   <section id="content-section"> 
    <h2 style="color:#ff9900">“They All Laughed When This 49 Year Old Mother Of Two Said She Could Do Twenty Pulls-Ups In a Row…</h2>
    <h2 style="color:#ff00ff">
    But The Laughs Stopped And Their Jaws Dropped When She Grabbed the Pull-up Bar and Effortlessly Banged Out Five, Ten, And Finally Twenty Pull-ups In A Row”
    </h2>
<div class="message" align="left">
    <p>
    Dear Friend,
    </p>
    <p>
    Frankly, it doesn’t matter if you’re struggling to do one pull-up or if you’re banging out multiple pull-ups and just want to take your game to the next level… I can help you get there. Just watch the video to the right if you’re not convinced.
    </p>
    <p>
    <b>I know what you’re thinking…</b> Yeah right!
    </p>
    <p>
    You probably think that I’m an anomaly, a freak of nature, or that pull-ups come naturally to me.
    </p>
    <p>
    Nothing could be further from the truth.
    </p>
    <p>
    You see, there was a time where I could barely hang from the pull-up bar and do a single pull-up. My brain could NOT get my muscles to pull me to the bar no matter how hard I tried and how strong my back was. These days I can knock out rep after rep of pull-ups because of a unique and relatively strange new training method that I’ve discovered.
    </p>
     </div>
   </section>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainContainer
        {
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 75%;
         }
#content-section{
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  margin-top:-18px;
  width:700px;

}
#content-section h2{

    text-align: center;
}

.message
{
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

first see the output here:

http://jsbin.com/gimovuzo/58

IF this answer helps tou please vote up. :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

Make a container of `width:80%` and `margin:0 auto`

This will help you have the main content in the middle of the page.

Now, you can put all your contents in to it.

Give grey color to you body & make a section inside the 80% wide container & give its BG white color.

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: grey;
}
#mainContainer{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#content-section{
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div id="mainContainer">
       <header></header>
       <section id="content-section"> </section>
       <footer></footer>
   </div>
</body>
```

This is one way of doing it. You can annytime replace the background-color with the images you want.

Comment: He's asking for a code that uses background and header images and your code is providing a solid grey background color with no header image instead.

Comment: this was just 1 another way of doing it. If somebody is doesnot know how to change the image background with bg-color, then i guess, he needs some more investigation on HTML & CSS

Comment: Here's what I have so far, by implementing the suggestions. I'm almost there....http://jsbin.com/qifew/1/edit

Comment: An "other way of doing something" is expected to output the same result as the OP is asking for, isn't it? Anyway, I was just suggesting an improvement.

Comment: Indeed. But he had no structure. So the motive here wat to build a skeleton. The properties can be modified only when you have the skeleton ready.

Comment: It's almost there. The text inside of the white box, I believe needs to be in another container/div? So that I can center w/in that div and also move the "Dear Friend..." text aligned to the left as well

Comment: for the image, do add this : img{
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: The OP should provide his code. He's actually just asking someone to create the code for him.